# i am getting a 50 different loops while including a variable in a string using ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get a string to run and print  on a seperate page with a certain string and a variable concatenated. i thought i had the code right but  all i get is a loop fifty timesthis is the code that i am using

```
f = File.open("urlfile.txt", "r")
    line = ""
    while (line = f.gets)
            puts "<outline text=\"\"  type=\"link\" url=\""+File.read("urlfile.txt")+"\" dateCreated=\"\"/>"
    end
    f.close
```

then this is what its spitting out
a loop that runs for about 50 times

```
http://washingtondc.craigslist.org
http://westpalmbeach.craigslist.org
http://westpalmbeach.craigslist.org
http://westslope.craigslist.org
http://westslope.craigslist.org
http://yubasutter.craigslist.org
http://yubasutter.craigslist.org
http://yuma.craigslist.org
http://yuma.craigslist.org
" dateCreated=""/>
```

and this is what the code should look like when it is spit out

Comment: Hint: You assigned the variable `line`. What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You are re-reading the file again inside the loop; as hinted by @Mark you have to be using line inside the string interpolation.

Aside: Perhaps its better to refactor the code to idiomatic Ruby; consider the following for instance:

```
lines = File.open('urlfile.txt', 'r').readlines

lines.each do |line|
  puts %|<outline text="" type="link" url="#{line.strip}" dateCreated=""/>|
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Jikku's answer is correct but if the file is large `readlines` will be expensive. In such case read file line by line (as you are already trying to do). Here is the correct code:

```
f = File.open("urlfile.txt", "r")
while (line = f.gets)
  puts "<outline text=\"\"  type=\"link\" url=\""+line.strip+"\" dateCreated=\"\"/>"
end
f.close
```

Its all your code, there are only two things that I've changed.

1. You had predefined `line` which was incorrect.
2. While you were already using `line` to iterate over your file line by line, by doing `File.read("urlfile.txt")` you were dumping the whole file again in each iteration. Hence "*so many loops*" as you described in your question.